# Why vstest.console just utilize 25 percent of CPU capacity?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

I use vstest.console to run MS unit tests. One thing that i found is that it utilizes only 25 percent of CPU capacity. Is there a way to make vstest.console to use more capacity of CPU to speed up test execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tests are spread across multiple assemblies, you may want to consider running them in parallel as mentioned here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/10/10/parallel-test-execution/